# Разная длина поля ввода input в разных браузерах

Tags: html, css, input, браузер

Сделал поле ввода с прилегающей к ней кнопкой и декоративную стрелку над кнопкой, которая бы на неё указывала.
Но оказалось, что в Internet Explorer длина поля ввода меньше, и из-за этого стрелка над кнопкой справа от input сдвигается.

Код:

```
<div id="subs">
    Your Email:<span class="arrow"><img src="greenarrow.png" width="60px" height="80px"></span><br>
    <input type="text" size="20">
    <input type="button" name="press" value="Subscribe!">
</div>
```

Результат в Google Chrome:

[image: chrome]

Результат в IE:

[image: ie]

Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задайте полю CSS свойство `width`.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.Subscribe {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="subs">
  Your Email:<span class="arrow"><img src="greenarrow.png" width="60px" height="80px"></span>
  <br>
  <input type="text" size="20">
  <input class="Subscribe" type="button" name="press" value="Subscribe!">
</div>
```

В этом случае кнопка в любом браузере будет одного размера